# Prove that $\ln(u)$ is subharmonic

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume that $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ is strictly positive such that the function $v=u \cdot e^{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} a_{i}x_{i}}$ is subharmonic, for any choice of the constants $a_{1},\ldots,a_{N}$.

> Prove that $\ln(u)$ is subharmonic in $\Omega$.

Of course I calculated $$\Delta v=e^{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} a_{i}x_{i}} \left(\Delta u + 2\sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} a_{i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} a_{i}^2 u \right).$$
It is clear that $\Delta v \geq 0$ because of subharmonic.

There is a hint saying that: "**It follows that $u \Delta u - |\nabla u|^2 \geq 0$, hence $\ln(u)$ is subharmonic**".

Please explain me, step by step, from where it follows and because we can say sth about $\ln(u)$ from that.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $\Delta(\log(u)) = u^{-2} (u \Delta u - | \nabla u|^2)$.

Comment: You have right but could you tell me why this statement $u \Delta u - |\nabla u|^2 \geq 0$ is true? I don't see it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Delta( \log{u}) = u^{-2} (u \Delta u - | \nabla u|^2)$, so it suffices to show that $u \Delta u - |\nabla u|^2 \geq 0$, as was hinted before.

You have computed that
$$
\Delta v = e^{a \cdot x} \left( \Delta u + 2 a \cdot \nabla u + u |a|^2 \right),
$$
and by assumption this is $\geq 0$. This holds pointwise (that is, for every $x \in \Omega$) as well as for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Therefore also
$$
\Delta u(x) + 2 a \cdot \nabla u(x) + u(x) |a|^2 \geq 0 ,
$$
where I've added the dependency on $x$ to be explicit. Now, let us focus our attention on any given $x_0 \in \Omega$. Then the above is still true, and furthermore we are allowed to choose any vector $a$, so choose $a = -\nabla(x_0)/u(x_0)$. Then, substituting this into the above,
$$
\Delta u(x_0) - 2 |\nabla u(x_0)|^2/ u(x_0) + |\nabla u(x_0)|^2 / u(x_0) \geq 0.
$$
Simplifying and multiplying through by $u(x_0)$ yields
$$
u(x_0) \Delta u(x_0) - | \nabla u(x_0)|^2 \geq 0.
$$
Since this holds for arbitrary $x_0$, then the inequality is proven.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I wouldn't have figured it out myself. Happy New Year :)